# Using pandas apply when requiring values from one column to create the values of another

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following simple case of a two column dataframe:

```
index a   b
0     1,4 0
1     2,5 0
2     9,7 0
3     6,1 0
4     4,8 0
```

If I want to have column 'b' become some function of column a I currently do:

```
for x in range(len(df)):
   val = df(x,0).split(",") 
   df(x,1) = somfunc(val)
```

But I've just read about 'pandas.apply'

**Would it be appropriate for me to use apply in this case or is there a more efficient way to run an operation such as this?** I can't quite figure out how to use apply for this scenario since apply seems to run the operation of every cell (within the filter) and I'm not sure how to reference other cells! It would be something like:

```
df.apply(somefunc(cell(~-1,~)) if x.name =='b')
```

But I'm unsure how the cell(~-1,~) would/should work!

EDIT 1:
(I've update the data frame to more correctly represent the issue!)
The expected output is the values multiplied by some other values (constant across rows, but it's an element wise operation on the values in cells from column a) and then summed together. If the value being used by some other values was (3, 4) then the output would be:

```
index a   b
0     1,4 19
1     2,5 26
2     9,7 55
3     6,1 22
4     4,8 44
```

Comment: "column 'b' become some function of column a" can you provide an example

Comment: @deadshot do you mean an example 'somefunc'? I was hoping to boil it down to the basics so it could be any function... but if thats not possible I can update the question to a more specific situation - should I?

Comment: can you post the expected output so it will be easy to understand

Comment: @deadshot I've made the question closer to my actual situation and included an example output

Comment: is the value always tuple with two numbers?

Comment: @deadshot the value always has the same number of number in it (in the case shown the number is 2, but in reality I'm dealing with larger numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to rewrite the function so as it takes a cell as input then use `apply`:

```
def somefunc(x):
    return sum(map(int, x.split(',')))

df['b'] = df['a'].apply(somefunc)
```

Output:

```
0     5
1     7
2    16
3     7
4    12
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use apply, loops are discouraged in pandas dataframes. With your situation you can use a lambda function to input different columns:

```
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: somefunc(x.a) if x.b == CONSTANT else x.b , axis=1)
```

When you apply to whole dataframe, and pass in x to lambda, you will have access to all columns i.e `x.a` and `x.b`, meaning x is the whole row.
you will need the else statement as well to fill the column correctly. Also don't forget the `axis=1` to make the apply move on columns.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to do simply something like this:

```
df['b']=df['a'].apply(somefunc)
```

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment!)